# When using open() as f: does f represent a new variable being created?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new(ish) to Python and I'm just trying to figure out how things work. When I use:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\KB\\Documents\\DataProcessing.txt', 'r') as f:
```

is f a new variable being created? Could I use any variable in its place? I've seen 'file' used as-well so I'm just wondering if this is an arbitrary name being assigned to a newly created variable? Could it be named anything or does it have to be f?

Comment: See the [Python reference documentation on the `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) and [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) where the `with` statement was first designed and proposed. The PEP is useful because it describes the original motivations of the design decisions; the documentation is useful because it summarizes the current state.

Comment: Yes, it is just like any other variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is f a new variable being created? Could I use any variable in its place?

Yes

```
with open('testfile.txt') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

is equivalent to

```
with open('testfile.txt') as lmnopqrstuvwxyz:
    print(lmnopqrstuvwxyz.read())
```

Comment: Happy to help, but honestly this is one of those little things that is great to test for yourself as you're learning these techniques. Try naming the variable different things, and doing things with it. The important thing to remember about the `with` context manager , is that it closes the file object after it exits the indented block.

Comment: Normally I would test on my own haha but it was embedded into a larger project I was working on and just wanted to get the answer while I continued working on other parts. Yeah I was able to figure out how with worked and why it's useful I just wasn't able to figure out exactly what f was haha, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `f` is a new variable.
Yes, you may use any other name.  `file` is a bad choice, because that's already a built-in name.  I often use something like the below, where `in_file` is the name of my input file.

```
with open(in_file) as csv_file:
```

Comment: it's a built-in name only for python 2; just to nitpick